# check if the database has same information / duplicate C#

Tags: c#

I want to check if the database has information with same SchoolYear, GradeLevel and Section(), If the statement was true I want to display a message that the information already exist. I already try some codes but i cant find whats missing

```
    r.Connect();
                r.cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblsection WHERE SchoolYear = @SchoolYear AND GradeLevel = @GradeLevel AND Section = @Section ",r.con);
                r.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolYear", cbSchoolYear.Text);
                r.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeLevel", cbGradeLevel.Text);
                r.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section",txtSectionName.Text);
                int UserExist = (int)r.cmd.ExecuteScalar();

               if (UserExist > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Section Already Exist");
                    r.Disconnect();
                }
```

Comment: This seems about right. What's not working?

Comment: @Vilx- its says" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual the corresponds to your MySQL server version  for  the right syntax to use  near 'FROM tblsection WHERE SchoolYear = '2017-2018' AND GradeLevel = 'Grade 2' AND Section = 'einstein' '  " then the highlighted part was the int UserExist = (int)r.cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: What types are the `SchoolYear` and `GradeLevel` columns?

Comment: They are both varchar

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd. I cannot see anything wrong, unless there's some invisible character there. Try this - remove the `WHERE` part and see if it works then. If not, then try an even simpler query - `select 2`. Try to find which part it is that throws it off.